# ClassPathXmlApplicationContext or WebApplicationContext for Web application without Spring Web

Tags: java, spring, web-services, war, applicationcontext

I want to use spring framework in my java web services app (deployed as a war). It doesn't have a UI or "visible face" to the user, so no ui framework implemented. Just services. So.. do I need a WebApplicationContext in order to load my beans configurations? Or just use ClassPathXmlApplicationContext and store the returned context in a singleton for subsequent uses? What's the recommended pattern in this scenario?

Comment: Are you using the DispatcherServlet to invoke your web-service handlers?

Comment: No, I'm not. I'm using Spring to wrap my pojos as web services.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing a rest service (but I also have an html page with javascript that documents the service). This is similar to what you need, I think, but you'll need to add a little more if you want to accept different headers (json, etc). I only need a handful of files to make it all work.

Here's my `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="testing-services" version="2.5" metadata-complete="true"
     xmlns="..." xmlns:xsi="..."
     xsi:schemaLocation="...">
<display-name>Testing Services</display-name>
<description>Services for selenium</description>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:persistence-config.xml
        classpath:transactions-config.xml
        classpath:testing-service-config.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>


<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/assets/pages/testing-service.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
</web-app>
```

I have an almost empty mvc-servlet.xml (it has an empty `beans` tag).

My `testing-service-config.xml`, referenced from `web.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="..."
   xmlns:xsi="..."
   xmlns:context="..."
   xsi:schemaLocation="...">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.myorg.app"/>


</beans>
```

And, finally, a spring configuration class, TestingServiceConfiguration:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ContentNegotiationConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.TEXT_HTML;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"com.myorg.app"})
public class TestingServiceConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.ignoreAcceptHeader(true);
    configurer.favorParameter(false);
    configurer.favorPathExtension(false);
    configurer.defaultContentType(TEXT_HTML);
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**").addResourceLocations("/assets/");
}

}
```